# perl -pi -e syntax with | or <

Tags: perl

If I want to replace all cases of foo with bar I simply do this.

```
perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/gi' /home/smith/myfile.txt
```

What if I only want to replace |foo| with |bar|?

Related question..What if I want to only replace >foo<   with   >bar< ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the | character:

`perl -pi -e 's/\|foo\|/\|bar\|/gi' /home/smith/myfile.txt`

Comment: The blackslashes in the substitution part (around `bar`) are superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
perl-pi -e 's/\Q|foo|\E/|bar|gi' /home/smith/myfile.txt
```

See `perldoc perlre` and search for `/Escape sequences/`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use proper quoting.  With ' quotes you're fairly safe to do what you want.  Except for things related to regexp characters, like the '|'.  so it would become this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\|foo\|/|bar|/gi' /home/smith/myfile.txt
```

The >foo< examples are easier because they're not regexp characters.